# How to call webviewdidfinishload delegate method of web view in cocoa?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa

I am using the WebViewDidFinishLoad delegate Method of WebView, but it is not getting called. Whenever I run the application and load request in a WebView.
Please tell me, how to call the method and which delegate I need to connect with the file owner.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said in a comment on another answer:

> ```
> - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(WebView *)webView{ NSLog(@"hello");}
> ```
>
> This method is not getting called.

That's because there is no such method.

WebView and UIWebView are not the same thing. The former is in the WebKit framework on the Mac; the latter is in the UIKit framework on iOS. WebView is not available on iOS and UIWebView is not available on the Mac.

UIWebView is a very stripped-down version of WebView. In particular, UIWebView has only one delegate protocol, of which `webViewDidFinishLoad:` is one of its methods, whereas WebView has no fewer than *six* delegate protocols.

`webViewDidFinishLoad:` only exists in the UIWebViewDelegate protocol, in the UIKit framework for iOS apps. Implementing it in a Mac application will achieve nothing, because nothing will call it.

> Please tell me how to call the method …

That will do you no good, because the whole point of implementing it is to find out when a load has finished. For you to call it yourself, you would need to know *when* to call it—i.e., when a load has finished. To know that, you would need to be told that a load has finished by WebKit. This is, as they say in logic, [begging the question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question).

The correct solution is to set the correct delegate to an object that conforms to the correct delegate protocol and implements the correct method. The correct delegate is [the WebView's frame load delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WebView/setFrameLoadDelegate%3a). Accordingly, the correct protocol is [the WebViewFrameLoadDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebFrameLoadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cat/WebFrameLoadDelegate). The correct method within that protocol that your frame load delegate must implement is [the `webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebFrameLoadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/webView%3adidFinishLoadForFrame%3a).

---

Cocoa Touch programmers with the same problem (`webViewDidFinishLoad:` not getting called) should make sure that their UIWebView's delegate is set to the correct object. If you're setting it in code, make sure you're talking to the correct web view—i.e., that your outlet to the web view is connected (if it's in a nib or storyboard), that you're loading the nib or storyboard (if it's in one), and that you're not clobbering the value of the outlet with a different web view (one from the nib, then one created in code, or vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

Try to add (And replace the `myUIWebView` with your UIWebView outlet name):

```
[myUIWebView setDelegate:self];
```

And in the header file, add `<UIWebViewDelegate>`, so you can use this methods:

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

}
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

}
```

Comment: - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(WebView *)webView{
   
    NSLog(@"hello");}This method is not getting called.

Comment: there is noting like setDelegate.

Comment: In your viewDidLoad, put  `[mywebview setDelegate:self];` and replace the `mywebview` with your UIWebView name.

Comment: @Alberto: That will only work for UIWebViews. WebViews do not respond to `setDelegate:`.

Comment: @PeterHosey , you are right . i am using the web view in cocoa application. how this delegate method works there

Comment: Wow, @PeterHosey. Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

First Bound ResourceDelegate of webview with file Owner

```
(void)webView:(WebView *)sender resource:(id)identifier didFinishLoadingFromDataSource:(WebDataSource *)dataSource
```

This will work for me perfectly.